# What the Steps to Create Android Application for Mobile Phone to Controlling the PC?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I'm doing a project is about Creating an Android Application for Mobile Phone to Control the PC 
I'm asking what the version of android should I use 
is android 2.3 good choice or there is another opinion ?
and what the programs I need to create this application ?
thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to add more context to your question and make it specific. Please take a moment to read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect the android to your PC over `Bluetooth` or `Wi-Fi`. So basically you will need two applications 1) a server running on your PC and 2) an app on the android side.

Android 2.3 should work fine, but you should be aware to not use newer API

If you will develop your PC program with Java you can use the `Robot` class to control the keyboard and mouse

See this project for an example:

[Remote-Desktop-Server](https://github.com/justin-taylor/Remote-Desktop-Server)

[Android-remote-client](https://github.com/justin-taylor/Android-remote-client)

Comment: thanks for your useful answer
I install eclips and sdk 
and start design the interface for this application
and I hope if you give me advise what the next step 
how I can made the connect between the application and the PC
I think about using MYSQL as a server 
thanks again

Comment: MySQL should be suitable as your database if you have a server that support multi-users. But if your application will run on Desktop PC for a single user, you can consider SQLite as your embedded database.